# apache-spark deployment: stand alone VS multiple VM's

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, alluxio

I have one machine on which to deploy Spark, Hadoop, and Tachyon.
 Are spark operations from hdfs/tachyon going to be faster on one node with all cores/RAM or a number of VM nodes evenly dividing the resources? 
Ram is < 200GB.

[Performance and Scalability of Broadcast in Spark](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~agearh/.../mosharaf-spark-bc-report-spring10.pdf) is quite old, but suggests that the increase network traffic could be a strong negative in the *all* vs VM's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably better to have multiple instances of the workers, while their is an increase in network overhead the JVM performance with a really large heap isn't great.

Comment: Thank you. Can you add anything quantatative to this? If I have a total of 64 cores and 192G ram, would 4, 3, or 2 nodes be best?